# Firebase not detecting signed in users

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

am trying to create an app whereby at the initial step, users log in and after keying a username and password, the list of users should be reflected in Firebase Authentication screen. I am able to log in with username but the list of users logged in is not reflected...

Please help!

This is my login page code:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

  class Login extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
  }

  class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    String _email, _password;

    checkAuthentification() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print(user);

        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentification();
  }

  login() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  showError(String errormessage) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('ERROR'),
            content: Text(errormessage),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'))
          ],
        );
      });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 300),
                    Container(
                      child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (input) {
                            if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Email';
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Email',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                          onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (input) {
                            if (input.length < 6)
                              return 'Provide Minimum 6 Characters';
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onSaved: (input) => _password = input),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    RaisedButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                      onPressed: login,
                      child: Text('LOGIN',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with list of logged in users?

Comment: Like when i sign in, it does not show in firebase that the user has signed in or been added, and when i add a user from firebase and try to login, it says "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."